# Not able to list files on S3-Bucket with amplify. [Error: Request failed with status code 403]

Tags: react-native, amazon-s3, expo, amazon-iam, aws-amplify

I´ve some problems with the Storage-libary of aws amplify in my react-native project (expo).

I´m trying to list files in the public-dict of my bucket. I´ve configured Amplify like described in the "Manual Setup"-section on https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/storage/getting-started/q/platform/js#using-amazon-s3

All other services like GraphQL or Auth are running as expected.

```
Amplify.configure({
Auth: {
    // REQUIRED only for Federated Authentication - Amazon Cognito Identity Pool ID
    identityPoolId: 'eu-central-1:xxx',

    // REQUIRED - Amazon Cognito Region
    region: 'eu-central-1',

    // OPTIONAL - Amazon Cognito User Pool ID
    userPoolId: 'eu-central-1_xxxx',

    // OPTIONAL - Amazon Cognito Web Client ID (26-char alphanumeric string)
    userPoolWebClientId: 'xxxx',

    oauth: {}
},
Storage: {
    AWSS3: {
        bucket: 'xxx', //REQUIRED -  Amazon S3 bucket name
        region: 'eu-central-1', //OPTIONAL -  Amazon service region

    }
}
}
```

When I call `await Storage.list(dict)` I get the following errors:

```
[ERROR] 30:16.771 axios-http-handler, [Error: Request failed with status code 403]
- node_modules/expo/build/logs/LogSerialization.js:168:14 in _captureConsoleStackTrace
- node_modules/expo/build/logs/LogSerialization.js:41:26 in serializeLogDataAsync
- ... 9 more stack frames from framework internals
...
[WARN] 30:16.773 AWSS3Provider - list error, [Error: Request failed with status code 403]
- node_modules/expo/build/logs/LogSerialization.js:168:14 in _captureConsoleStackTrace
- node_modules/expo/build/logs/LogSerialization.js:41:26 in serializeLogDataAsync
- ... 9 more stack frames from framework internals
```

The auth-policy of my identityPoolId has the right settings from my point of view:

```
{
        "Action": [
            "s3:*"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::xxx",
            "arn:aws:s3:::xxx/public/*"
        ],
        "Effect": "Allow"
    }
```

And the CORS-Konfiguration as well:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
<ID>S3CORSRuleId1</ID>
<AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
<AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
<AllowedMethod>HEAD</AllowedMethod>
<AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
<AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
<AllowedMethod>DELETE</AllowedMethod>
<MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
<ExposeHeader>x-amz-server-side-encryption</ExposeHeader>
<ExposeHeader>x-amz-request-id</ExposeHeader>
<ExposeHeader>x-amz-id-2</ExposeHeader>
<ExposeHeader>ETag</ExposeHeader>
<AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

What am I doing wrong? Does someone have an idea what I´m missing in my settings. Is it necessary to pass the jwtToken to the Storage-operations?

I would appreciate it if someone could help me.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I´ve found the solution. The identity pool auth policy was created by SAM and missed the AssumeRolePolicyDocument.

Comment: Could you elaborate the answer? Where is AssumeRolePolicyDocument located?